# WMS Geometry Vector point label Styling

Tags: openlayers-2, sld, ext-js

How can we add category based styling to geometry point
my application show geoserver rendered map, and all the map POI are directly fetched from database and shown to the map.i need know how we can add different style for different points
please help me

database used is POSTGIS

Comment: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-cookbook/points.html

Answer (score 1):

There are several options I can think of, but there are probably more and better ways to do it.

1. Depending on how many styles you need, you could create a new rule for each style you need. Set a filter on each type of style like this:

   ```
   <ogc:Filter>
      <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyName>POI_TYPE</ogc:PropertyName>
        <ogc:Literal>Rainbow</ogc:Literal>
       </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
    </ogc:Filter>
   ```
2. You also use the database to color you POI's differently. You can fill your database with HEX colors and tell the SLD to use it like this:

   ```
   <PointSymbolizer>
    <Graphic>
     <Mark>
      <Fill>
       <CssParameter name="fill">
       <ogc:PropertyName>SLD_COLOUR</ogc:PropertyName>
       </CssParameter>
      </Fill>
      <WellKnownName>circle</WellKnownName>
     </Mark>
     <Size>5.0</Size>
    </Graphic>
   </PointSymbolizer>
   ```

You can also look at 
http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/SLD-for-attribute-based-polygon-td3789822.html

I have tried to do this with the "WellKNownName" shapes, but this has failed.